# Ordenar lineas de un fichero

Tags: python

Necesito que las lineas que cumplan

```
lect_linea[0]=='"PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond"'and float(lect_linea[60])>30
```

Se ordenen de menor a mayor por el valor almacenado en `lect_linea[60]`
he probado usando:

```
g.write(sorted(linea, key=lambda x: float(x[60])))
```

en vez de:

```
g.write(linea)
```

pero me da un error de sintaxis.
Estas serian unas de las varias lineas del fichero de entrada:

> "Number_of_sentences_for_full_data"", 4, ""Elevation_Degrees"", 74, ""Azimuth_degrees"", 35, ""Sentence_1_of_2"", 1, ""Number_of_satellites_in_view"", 14, ""Satellite_PRN_number"", 27, ""SNR"", ""42"", ""CheckSum_data"", 10, ""Satellites_in_view"", ""$GPGSV"", ""Id"", ""NMEA GSV"""
>   "Latitud"", 3928.752338, ""HorizontalDilutionofPosition"", 0.4, ""TimeinSecondsSinceLastDGPSUpdate"", ""51.1"", ""Direccion_longitud"", ""W"", ""GlobalPositioningSystemFixData"", ""$GPGGA"", ""Direccion_Latitud"", ""N"", ""FixQuality"", 1, ""DGPSStationIDNumber"", ""51.1"", ""Altitude"", 19.6, ""Geoid_height_units"", ""M"", ""ChecksumData"", ""M"", ""Fixtakenat_hh_mm_ss_UTC"", 163504, ""NumberofSatellitesTracked"", 28, ""Geoid_height"", 51.1, ""Altitude_units"", ""M"", ""Id"", ""NMEA GGA"", ""Longitud"", 20.256369"
>   "PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond"", 4.2033262571598, ""DriftUncertaintyNanosPerSecond"", """", ""AccumulatedDeltaRangeState"", 4, ""ReceivedSvTimeNanos"", 491721918491620.0, ""TimeUncertaintyNanos"", """", ""SnrInDb"", """", ""FullBiasNanos"", -1.2125108815424e+18, ""State"", 47, ""MultipathIndicator"", ""1"", ""AgcDb"", """", ""PseudorangeRateMetersPerSecond"", -4.2472825078449, ""TimeNanos"", 40458000000, ""Svid"", 7, ""AccumulatedDeltaRangeUncertaintyMeters"", 3.4028234663853e+38, ""AccumulatedDeltaRangeMeters"", -139.4196963987, ""BiasUncertaintyNanos"", 5.3149323606571, ""BiasNanos"", 0, ""CarrierPhaseUncertainty"", """", ""CarrierFrequencyHz2"", ""\n"", ""TimeOffsetNanos"", 0, ""DriftNanosPerSecond"", """", ""CarrierFrequencyHz"", """", ""ConstellationType"", ""1"", ""CarrierCycles"", """", ""ReceivedSvTimeUncertaintyNanos"", 167, ""CarrierPhase"", """", ""LeapSecond"", """", ""HardwareClockDiscontinuityCount"", 0, ""ElapsedRealtimeMillis"", 14068885, ""Id"", ""Raw"", ""Cn0DbHz"", 16.816381454468"
>   "GPS_time"", ""2018-06-08 16,35,21"", ""Altitude"", 70.782148, ""Longitude"", -0.33762, ""Provider"", ""gps"", ""Latitude"", 39.479188, ""Speed"", 0, ""Id"", ""Fix"", ""Accuracy"", 4"

Este es mi código:

```
f=open('C:\\Users\\Xabier\\Desktop\\good_shit.txt','r')
g = open("middle.txt","w")
#h = open("end.txt","w")

while True:
    linea=f.readline()
    if not linea:break

    full_linea=linea.splitlines()
    lect_linea=linea.split(',')

    if (lect_linea[0]=='"PseudorangeRateUncertaintyMetersPerSecond"'and float(lect_linea[60])>30):
        #print (linea)

        g.write(linea)


    elif (lect_linea[0]=='"Number_of_sentences_for_full_data"'and float(lect_linea[3])>20 and float(lect_linea[9])>4):    

            #print (linea)

            g.write(linea)

    elif (lect_linea[0]=='"GPS_time"'):                      
            #print (linea)
            g.write(linea)


f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: ¿Quieres ordenar el contenido de la línea o las lineas entre si? Si quieres ordenar las líneas (la posición que cada una ocupa en el archivo) la opción más simple si no tienes problema de memoria es almacenarlas en una lista todas, aplicar `sort` sobre ella y no sobre cada `linea`  y después escribirlas todas en el fichero. Si agregas un fragmento del archivo original representativo y la salida esperada es más fácil darte una respuesta concreta para el caso.

Comment: Quiero ordenar las lineas, si, pero no me deja guardarlo en lista, me dice que 
AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

Comment: ¿Que quieres hacer con las lineas que no cumplen el condicional?¿Las ignoras?¿Las almacenas también en el fichero de salida?¿Si es esto último en que orden deben de ir con respecto a las que si cumplen la condición?

Comment: Las ignoro, solo necesito un fichero con las lineas que cumplan la condición. Ese fichero lo consigo generar, el problema está en ordenarlo. Actualmente he metido toda la linea en una lista pero la guarda como un unico elemento. Creo que necesito una lista con las lineas que contenga otra con las lecturas. Si hiciera esto, podría ordenar las listas entre ellas dependiendo de los valores de alguna lectura?